# Styling issue on error message popups

Tags: feature-request

I was reading some old, locked [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature) and, without thinking, tried to vote on a comment.

[image]

Of course, the obligatory warning that I'm not allowed to vote on locked posts came up. Note the `x` button and its position. Is there any way the styling on this could be fixed, so that it, along with the text, is centered vertically and with the correct horizontal padding?

The fix:

`div.message-text` : use `padding-left: 40px;` and `padding-left: 10px;`

`div.message-close`: use `margin-top: 12px;` instead of `margin-top: 8px;`

These style changes would make these popups look a lot better:

[image]

However, this would need to only be applied to warnings that are one line, since multiple-line warnings look fine as is.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind digging around a little and proposing the CSS changes you think would fix the issue? I'm feeling lazy tonight.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I put the margins that should be changed. It applies to `<div title="close this message (or hit Esc)" class="message-close">×</div>`—the X button.

Comment: Yup, I was referring to that class selector and the *fixing the horizontal spacing* part of your post (and I'm pretty sure word-wrapping is the only thing that makes you believe multi-line warnings are exempt from that).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Finally got back to my computer, so I was able to check it out. `padding-right: 35px;` should be changed to `padding-right: 40px;` on `div.message-text` to fix the horizontal spacing. The reason I think multi-line warnings are fine is because they are aesthetically pleasing. Having the button at the top-right corner is fine. However, with singe-line warnings, it looks better to have it centered vertically.